# This is how i am building the image and deployments within shell script which is being called from jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

In K8s world and in the shell script i have below content

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t imagename:1 .

kubectl delete -f services/nodeport.service.yml
kubectl delete -f deployments/springapsimplehellopod.deployment.yml
kubectl apply -f deployments/springapsimplehellopod.deployment.yml
kubectl apply -f services/nodeport.service.yml
kubectl apply -f services/loadbalancer.service.yml
```

Am i following correct standards ? What is disadvantages of not using image registry rather built image will be kept in local docker and from the newly created image i am creating deployments and services

Comment: How will you backout when the new image has an issue?

Comment: An image registry is basically required when using Kubernetes.  I'd suggest generating an image tag (in your Groovy pipeline code) based on the build number, commit hash, or current time.  You should not need to delete the existing objects before doing `kubectl apply`.

Comment: If you will use `kubectl apply` it should apply new configuration if there is resource with the same name in the same namespace (unless if it will encounter immutable parameter). Also did you consider using `Helm chart`? Could you elaborate or provide use scenario how it would looks like?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using script, you can just point folder with your YAMLs. It's mentioned in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#using-kubectl)

> Use `kubectl apply -f <directory>`. This looks for Kubernetes configuration in all `.yaml`, `.yml`, and `.json` files in  and passes it to apply.

```
$ kubectl apply -f ./tst
service/nginx created
statefulset.apps/web created
service/nginx unchanged
persistentvolume/pv0003 created
```

Also you don't need to delete your deployments, as `kubectl apply` will reconfigure deployment.

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/mywebtestapp-deployment created
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ vi deployment.yaml             # editing container name from nginx to httpd
user@cloudshell:~ (project)$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/mywebtestapp-deployment configured
```

Until you will want to change `immutable` field.

```
The Service "nginx" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
```

In this situation you would need to delete this resource and create new one.

Regarding best practice using image registry it might be opinion based and depends on your needs.
You can check [this article](https://thenewstack.io/how-a-container-registry-can-both-save-and-harm/) or check [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369591/what-are-the-advantages-running-a-local-docker-registry).

You could also check [Helm - The package manager for Kubernetes](https://helm.sh/) if you would like for example divide your application into helm charts.